# How do I run a query again if the limit is not reached? - Firebase - Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

My documents in Firestore contain contain an array of dates as strings ("MM/dd/yyyy"). I want to rerun 'loadposts()' with a new date each time until I reach 5 documents. Any Ideas?

```
var queryDate = Date()
let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    
    func loadPosts (date: Date) {
      let firestoreRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts")
          .whereField("dates", arrayContains: dateformatter.string(from: date))
          .limit(to: 5)
    
        firestoreRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if snapshot?.count < 5 {
            self.queryDate += 86400
            loadPosts(date: queryDate)
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: Are you looking to rerun the function until the query contains 5 documents? Or are you looking to rerun the function until you have fetched a total of 5 documents from Firestore?

Comment: @Tadreik Rerun the function until I have fetched 5 documents from Firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a recursive one.

```
var queryDate = Date()
var count: Int = 0

let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    
    func loadPosts (date: Date) {
      let firestoreRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts")
          .whereField("dates", arrayContains: dateformatter.string(from: date))
          .limit(to: 5)
    
        firestoreRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        count += snapshot?.count
        if snapshot?.count < 5 {
            self.queryDate += 86400
            loadPosts(date: queryDate)
            if count < 5 {
                loadPosts(date: )
            }
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the help, but this did not work. It only runs loadPost() one more time. It does not rerun loadPosts() until there are 5 documents

Comment: nevermind, it works. I just realized i had lots or "return"  values in the errors and such

Answer (score 0):

I edited Tadreik's answer a bit

```
var queryDate = Date()
var count: Int = 0

let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    
    func loadPosts (date: Date, limit: Int) {
      let firestoreRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts")
          .whereField("dates", arrayContains: dateformatter.string(from: date))
          .limit(to: limit)
    
        firestoreRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if count < 5 {
            count += snapshot?.count
            self.queryDate += 86400
            loadPosts(date: queryDate, limit: 5 - count)    
         }
.
.
.
```